# Tor support on MyMonero.com

Tags: tor, mymonero, api, mitm, javascript

Many privacy focused Tor users are interested or have the potential to be interested in Monero. IP address protection is important to Tor users.

Why was Tor removed from the CORS headers on the MyMonero API?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There was evidence of several cases of Tor exit nodes injecting JavaScript into the page. The developers of [MyMonero](https://mymonero.com/#/) did not want to risk MITM attacks leading to more theft of Monero funds.

At some point in the future, time permitting a better Tor hosting infrastructure may allow Tor to be re-enabled. Right now there are higher priorities. Security concerns trump any convenience factor that Tor usage at MyMonero may provide some uses.

For best privacy and security it is recommended that users run their own full nodes and keep most Monero in cold storage. Web wallets should not be recommended as primary wallets for anyone whose top priority is privacy or security